# Xcode extensions keyboard shortcuts stop working after restart

Tags: xcode

This used to happen in Xcode 8 and now it's happening in Xcode 9 GM.

Basically, I assign keyboard shortcuts to Xcode extensions actions and they work during the session. After Xcode is restarted, they stop working. They are still correctly assigned, there are no conflicts, but alas they do not work.

To make them work again I have to manually remove them and then re-add them.

All default shortcuts work normally and the extensions themselves work when activated from the menu. Only the extensions keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is still happening, however, the actual shortcuts can be restored in Xcode by running System Preferences -> Extensions and clicking on Xcode.

Comment: Did you file a bug report with Apple? Okay, I hate when people ask _me_ that, so I should apologize. I'm not trying to yank your chain, I'm just suggesting that this seems like a very legitimate thing to let Apple know about.

Comment: I didn't actually think of that before - thanks. I filed a bug report now. It's true that it's not as annoying with the above workaround, but yes they should at least know about it, if they don't already.